# Flutter: How to enable kotlin&swift support for existing flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a flutter project without adding kotlin and swift code support to my project.How to add kotlin & swift code support to the existing flutter project without affecting my project code so for I done

Comment: i would simply compare two empty projects: one with and one without support to kotlin/swift

Comment: my old project just look like the one with kotlin support only difference is code inspection not working in mainactivity.kt. So i thought i haven't added kotlin support

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to add a single file in Kotlin format (example under android>main>java>your packagename>test.kt) and it will automatically upgrade. Can be an empty file. Add it using android studio.